# Drupal 7 - View xxx could not be found (using services module)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal 7 Services (API creation). I read a post from https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/services/

I have installed the required modules and configured all as they said however, I did not integrate any authentication under structure > Services

Thus under Authentication tab, its saying:

No authentication modules are enabled, all requests will be anonymous.

Also, I did not checked the following under "EDIT" tab:

Session authentication

OAuth authentication

However, when I want to access the API through `http://localhost/project-name/myrestapi/views/myrestapi`
It is saying that `["View myrestapi could not be found"]`

Please note, the view is showing the below result from the admin panel:

```
array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'title' => 'About Us',
  )),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it was the `services_views` module(7.x-1.4) I was previously installed. I uninstalled the module and install the previous version of services_views 7.x-1.3. Then I created another view e.g. Rest with another Services and renamed the path (Path:/rest).

Now, I can accessing the path like:

```
http://localhost/drupal767/myrestapi/views/rest.json?display_id=services_1
http://localhost/drupal767/myrestapi/rest.json
```

The result looks like:

```
[{"node_title":"<a href=\"/drupal767/about-us\">About Us</a>"}]
```